# In Coq, what tactic can I use to remove a True precondition from a hypothesis

Tags: coq

One of my hypothesis is an implication with an always-true condition (`x=x->P`). What tactic can I use to rewrite this hypothesis into its conclusion `P`? The only way I could think of is an awkward combination of assert, apply, and rename. There ought to be a better way.

```ml
Theorem myexample: forall T (x: T) (P: Prop), (x = x -> P) -> P.
Proof.
  intros T x P H.
  (* At this point, the hypothesis is "H: x=x->P" *)
  assert (H': x=x). { reflexivity. }
  apply H in H'. clear H. rename H' into H.
  (* Now the hypothesis is "H: P" *)
  apply H.
Qed.
```

ps.: In this particular example, we could also prove with `apply H; reflexivity`. But my question is about how to clean up the hypothesis without touching the goal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [specialize](https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.19.0/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.specialize) tactic

```ml
specialize (H eq_refl).
```

`eq_refl` is a constructor of type `eq`, which is hiding behind the `=` notation

Another way, if your hypothesis have something non-trivial in premise, is to construct it using tactics ([tactics in terms](https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.19.0/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#tactics-in-terms))

As you mentioned yourself, premise of `H` can be constructed using `reflexivity`, so here it is:

```ml
specialize (H ltac:(reflexivity)).
```

Comment: When I tried using eq_refl, I got an error saying: The term "eq_refl" has type "RelationClasses.Reflexive Logic.eq" while it is expected to have type
 "x = x". Turns out that I had Imported another module that shadowed the definition of eq_refl. My workaround was `specialize (H Coq.Init.Logic.eq_refl)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ssreflect, you can, after the `intros`, use:

```
move: (H erefl) => {}H.
```